# What is the procedure to do Azure AD authentication in a Drupal site?

Tags: azure, drupal, azure-authentication

I want to do Azure Ad Authentication to a Drupal Site. What the procedure that i need to do. Any module which will help to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, this is the first result from Google: https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect_windows_aad.

Comment: First, you didn't mention what version of Drupal are you using. Not all modules are available for all Drupal versions. Second, did you try at least to google for i.e. "drupal azure authentication"? I did and https://www.drupal.org/project/azure_auth appeared as first result.